# Your comments are welcome or welcomed?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I am sending one of my papers to someone by email. I like to know what he think about my paper. So I write

> **Your comments are welcome.**

Or should I write

> **Your comments are welcomed.**

?

Comment: I too just had a block. ("ideas are welcome" or "ideas are welcomed"?)  But I think it's best to use 'welcome', though I am only going on intuition.